# TypeScript compile error using a component library created with Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following this post https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

The goal is is we want a common library of core services and components that other projects can use.  I am having a problem with services.  Here is my first service generated with CLI

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  constructor() { }

  sayHello() {
      console.log("Hello From Example Service");
  }

}
```

I put it into its own module like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [ExampleService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

We ultimately will have several services inside CoreModule.  Inside the project where I created the service, I import the new module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// import my module 
import { CoreModule } from './modules/core/core.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can then use this in a component inside that project:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ExampleService } from './modules/core/example.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) { 
     exampleService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

Now I want to create an NPM package with this as my first component.  I create the packagr.json and the type file and run these 3 commands as per above post:
npm run packagr; 
cd dist; 
npm pack

So far all good.  Now I go to use this in another project by doing this:

npm install myframework-0.0.0.tgz

I can see myframework in my node_modules inside this project.  I can see my core module defined and I can see my example service.  Now, I am simply trying to use it in this new project like this:

In my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// import it here
import { CoreModule } from 'myframework';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This must be fine as the compiler does not complain.  Finally, I want to use that service somewhere:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//these don't work
//import { ExampleService } from 'myframework';
import { ExampleService } from 'myframework/CoreModule';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

     constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) {
        exampleService.sayHello();
    }
}
```

The compiler does not like my import statements
- with the first I get "myframework has not export member Example Service"
- with the second import I get "cannot find module myframework/CoreModule"

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Are you sure you exports the service from the index file in your ‘myframework’ folder?

Comment: @ZeevKatz not sure what you mean.  If you mean public_api.ts in producing library, yes.  In the node_modules of consuming project, I can see example service in myframework.js and it has export { CoreModule, ExampleService as ɵa };

Comment: I think it’s should be {ea as ExampleService}. 

Comment: @ZeevKatz I switched it up and used the yeoman generator https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-library to generate my library and it works.  Thanks for jumping in.